# WebView ignores target-densitydpi

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I am building an App with Phonegap.
I defined the densitydpi with the viewport meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="target-densitydpi=device-dpi, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

Until some days ago everything was fine and the pixel ratio of the page was correct.
Now the `target-densitydpi=device-dpi` seems to be ignored and the web page seems to be displayed at a pixel ratio of 1, and i can't figure out why it doesn't use the real pixel ratio of the device, that before was correct.

I tested on a Nexus 5 with Android 4.4.2 and a Nexus 4 with Android 4.4.2

I'm compiling the project with `cordova build android`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**target-densitydpi** attribute is now deprecated.

Please go through this blog [Viewport target-densitydpi support](https://petelepage.com/blog/2013/02/viewport-target-densitydpi-support-is-being-deprecated/) Line drawns from that blog is

> Support for target-densitydpi in the viewport meta tag was recently removed from WebKit and with Chrome for Android moving forward to current revisions on WebKit, this change is now rolling out in Android.

Here is the fix from the blog

**An Easy, Quick Fix**

> You can fix it easily by serving the same mark-up `(including viewport)` to Chrome for Android as you serve to `mobile Safari (which never supported target-densitydpi)`.

Comment: Please change the url of your reference to start with http instead of https. It seems that it is not working (probably https is no longer supported).